# R Programming:How to calculate the area of a circle using an loop and function from a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I have a numeric vector of 5 radii. I wrote the following function to calculate the area of a circle if one of the arguments in my function = 'AC'. I want to write a loop that using my function to calculate the area of a circle using radii in a numeric vector and print the results. How do I go about solving my problem in R?

**Function:**

```
area.volume =function(var1,R) {
    if (toupper(var1)=='AC') {
        pi*R^2
    } else if (toupper(var1)=='CC') {
        4/3*pi*R 
    } else if (toupper(var1)=='VS') {
        4*pi*R^2
    } else print("your method is not supported")
}
```

Vector of radii: `c(20,10,4,34)`

I would like my function to loop through the vector and calculate the are using the line:
`if (toupper(var1)=='AC'){ pi*R^2 }`.

Answer (score 1):

your function already fulfills your spec through vectorization:

```
area.volume('AC', c(20,10,4,34))
[1] 1256.63706  314.15927   50.26548 3631.68111
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I solve my problem inserting my function in a loop and explicitly using a print function?

Comment: You can do the following. But be advised that you should always try to use the vectorised version in R. : `x <- c(20,10,4,34);
for (i in seq_along(x)){
  print( area.volume('AC', x[i]) );
}`